# Is it ok to use in-process cache in node.js (backed by Buffer)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, v8

Node.JS has memory limitation 1Gb, also it has GC, so it's not good to use it for storing large amount of objects that consume lots of memory.

But, Node.JS also has the Buffer class, it's stored outside of v8. And, while the single Buffer also should be less than 1Gb it's ok to have multiple Buffers with the total size > 1Gb.

So, is it ok to use Buffer in Node.js to create the in-process Cache? In my case I don't need top performance, the average performance would be fine. Can we expect that it would be at least not ten times worse than Redis?

Comment: As with pretty much all performance questions, it depends on the details of your particular situation so if you really want to know, devise a simple test and measure.